# Python on Mac OS; No matching distribution found for PyQt5

Tags: python, macos, pyqt, pyqt5

1. In cause of conflicting PyQt5 and PyQt4 I deleted both from folders, and now trying to make my script run.

   ```
   ./labelImg.py
   ```

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "./labelImg.py", line 24, in
>   
>       from PyQt4.QtGui import * ImportError: No module named PyQt4.QtGui

2. Tried to install PyQt4 by "pip install pyqt":

> Collecting pyqt
>
> Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pyqt (from
>   versions: ) No matching distribution found for pyqt

3. Tried to check pip :

   ```
   which pip
   ```

All is fine. The same "which" for PyQt4 has no result at all... just passed by...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tried everything ... every single pip, python version, modules ...

My decision was to reinstall Mac OS and use only necessary files to launch what I need. So there is very less information about general concept Mac OS and Python. As I figured out ...

1. There is package installation. (By mouse and finder).
2. Homebrew installation (environment wich isolates you libraries and modules for python. More safer and can be restored with git repo. (Terminal)
3. custom configuration with own paths.

There are a lot of guides how to to it, but the main point is to use only one method. Moreover I had some:

> ImportError: No module named PyQt4.QtCore

We can fix it by changing .py file and put there PyQt5 i.e.
However, if you have updated everything, and it doesn't work, try to call

`Python3 your_script.py`

Good luck guys!

Answer (score 1):

First there is no need to delete PyQt4 or PyQt5 because there is not conflict.  Both can be installed and coexist, they have different module/package names after all.

And those package names are also the names of the packages in the Python Package Index, not *pyqt*, but *PyQt4* and *PyQt5* ([PyPI search for „pyqt“](https://pypi.org/search/?q=pyqt)).

Comment: I had a case when paths where totally misplaced. Qt4 was at Python3 libs/framework, Qt5 - at Python 2.7 :)